# Nexus 4 with Ubuntu touch locked for 24140377 minutes!

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lock-screen

My phone has locked itself, the lock screen says:

---

Device Locked

You have been locked out due to too many failed passcode attempts.

Please wait 24140376 minutes and then try again...

---

I believe the phone is fully updated (OTA9?).

I have important data, so do not wish to reset the phone.

:(

Comment: The OS wants you to wait 46 years to use it again. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Exactly. I really can't wait that long... lol

Answer (score 1):

Is your device in developer mode?

If yes, you could first try copying your home directory, then reset your device, and finally write your home directory back to your device.

edit:

So here are some instructions (untested) how you could backup your home directory:

1. PlugIn your device via usb to your desktop computer.
2. run `adb devices`; Your device should now be listed, if it is in developer mode.
3. run `adb pull /home/phablet/. /home/userName/your/backupDir/.` to download the home folder to your pc.
4. Make a coffee until its done...
5. Now you might want to know where your notes are placed? I had success on searching them with this command: `grep -r "Some pattern you remember of your notes" /home/userName/your/backupDir/`. The output shows the file(s) containing your pattern, i. e. your notes-data-file.

Comment: Yes, it's in developer mode. Do I use the computer to log in and copy my home directory? (I'm not exceedingly experienced).
Will this save data from software? For example, I have a lot of notes stored in the the notes program; I don't want to lose them.

Comment: I just noticed; the date is set at the 19th of January 1970!!
Is there a way I can reset the date?

Comment: Hey Caleb, I'm going to send you the instruction you need by editing my previous post, soon.

Comment: Can't I just fix the problem? Why reset the phone?

Comment: @Caleb, have you fixed your problem? If yes tell us what you have done.:)