# Access phone data

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Yesterday my phone dropped, and it's still alive, well... sortoff.
The glass is shattered quite badly in one of the corners, making me unable to unlock my device.
now here is the question: how do I access the data on the phone?
please note that I CANNOT enter my device PIN to unlock it.
the data that is on there is quite important to me so I really want it back.

Comment: Have the glass repaired.

Comment: I already got a new phone so that would be quite a waste.

Comment: That depends on how important the data on there is to you.

Comment: it are pictures of me and my grandma mostly.
sadly, my grandma is nomore so thats why they are quite important to me.
but I don't want to replace the screen as that is quite expensive.
and if there is a way to recover the data without replacing the screen then why replace the screen...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nexus 4 with Ubuntu touch locked for 24140377 minutes!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717499/nexus-4-with-ubuntu-touch-locked-for-24140377-minutes)

Comment: @eDeviser it seems indeed that this question has been done there too, but I couldn't find it since well, I obviously searched for different stuff, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device is in developer mode you can copy all your data over USB with 'adb pull'.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can´t,
to use your phone, you need to have to unlock your phone to give access.
However if you have your phone on dev. mode like [eDeviser](https://askubuntu.com/users/460843/edeviser) said, it is indeed possible.
It is also possible to use Jailbreak/Root.
Dont you have a SD card inside of it?

You can try to repair your phone, or else. if you have a computer with windows on it. you should look at [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-s/help/broken-screen-to-retrieve-files-off-t1573744) topic.

Hacking is also a way. but thats far more difficult than it has to be.

Comment: It has been solved.

and yes, I did have an SD card in there, but Ubuntu Touch automatically saves camera pictures and such on the device itself and I can't find a way to change it.