# Access to data on phone with dead screen?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, remote-access

I have an orginal BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu edition.
Problem is the screen is now dead. There is still guarantee on it, but if I send it to BQ, they are forced to wipe all data due to EU rules or something like that.
Is it possible to get pictures etc. from the phone without using the screen?
If not, I'll try to change the screen myself and void the warranty.

Comment: @DavidFoerster what does that mean? Localized?

Comment: @Hellreaver: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4818/271411

Comment: @DavidFoerster you're telling me that nobody else has this phone, and even if they do, that they won't know what to do if the screen dies? Whatever you say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nexus 4 with Ubuntu touch locked for 24140377 minutes!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717499/nexus-4-with-ubuntu-touch-locked-for-24140377-minutes)

Comment: With a USB OTG cable, you might be able to connect a mouse or keyboard to get past the screen lock (I haven't verified this).  If that works, you'd be able to transfer the files off via MTP.

Comment: No luck following the guide link posted by eDeviser...